# Power BI Matrix % per row as graph

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have created a matrix in Power BI which shows the % as % per row, I want to show this as a graph but it seems I can only do % of grand total. Is there a way around this? Image of the data structure in the matrix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a measure similar to:

```
Data % = 
  DIVIDE(
    SUM(YourTable[Data]),
    CALCULATE( SUM(YourTable[Data]), REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[LTV Split]) )
  )
```

Update the table and column names accordingly.